# Send attachment from s3 bucket using Mailgun

Tags: mailgun, inline-attachments

Trying to send an email with inline images embed. Only the file is not located on the server it is in an S3 bucket. How can this be done? The standard API doesn't seem to be reading the images into the email.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = Mailgun::create('PRIVATE_API_KEY', 'https://API_HOSTNAME');
$domain = "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME";
$params = array(
      'from'    => 'Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
      'to'      => 'bob@example.com',
      'subject' => 'Hello',
      'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
      'html'    => '<html>Inline image: <img src="cid:test.jpg"></html>',
      'inline' => array(
          array('filePath' => '/path/to/image.jpg'))
    );

  # Make the call to the client.
  $result = $mgClient->messages()->send($domain, $params);
```

By using inline param you can send the images with the correct path.